# Changing the background color of a <div> section

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use `jQuery` to change the background color of a `<div>` section when pressing on a button, and below is the code to do that. Why isn't it working?

**HTML file**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
#name{
background-color: #FFFFF2;
width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="bgcolor" value="Change color"/>
<div id="name">
Abder-Rahman
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$("bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#name").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#8B008B'},
        "fast");}
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. Your selector is wrong: `$("#bgcolor")`
2. You're missing a closing `</div>` tag.
3. You need [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) to animate `background-color`.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="bgcolor" value="Change color"/>
<div id="name">
Abder-Rahman
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#name").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#8B008B'},
        "fast");}
);
```

Your code, fixed (and working with jQueryUI included): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rAVj9/

Comment: By asking Marcos from `http://marcofolio.net/`, I had to add this around my jQuery: `$(function() {....});`. For the reason to do that, he said: `To execute jQuery code, the document has to be fully ready to attach the desired handlers.`

Comment: @Med-SWEng: That's correct--I couldn't tell if you were sharing your script from *inside* your `$(document).ready(...)` handler or not. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery website:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.)

Use jquery UI package to animate colors.

Comment: You could change the class name using a timer...and simulate animation by creating several classes (i.e. #name0..9).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you include the CSS selector inside the jQuery that you wish to target.

```
$("bgcolor").click(function(){
```

Should be:

```
$("#bgcolor").click(function(){
```

Because you are targeting an ID.

Comment: How can I do what you mention by: `Ensure you include the CSS selector inside the jQuery that you wish to target.`? Thanks

Comment: You have given the input an ID of **bgcolor** which in CSS terms, is identified by a hash symbol e.g. `#bgcolor`. Similarly with classes, they are identified by a period/full stop e.g. `.bgcolor`. You need to make sure that when you are targeting these in jQuery you are including the CSS selector character (the hash or the period).

Comment: You may already understand, but if not, see http://bit.ly/2QVpu8 which is another Stack question on CSS selectors.