# jQuery - Background color not changing

Tags: jquery, background-color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)
>   [Changing the background color of a <div> section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622170/changing-the-background-color-of-a-div-section)

I have the following code trying to change the background color of a text after pressing a button. The case is that it is not doing what it is intended to do. Why is that? What is going wrong here.

**HTML code**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
#name{
background-color: #FFFFF2;
width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="bgcolor" value="Change color"/>
<div id="name">
Abder-Rahman
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$("#bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#name").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#8B008B'},
        "fast");}
);
```

**EDIT**

I want to notice that I have a folder called: jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom, and this is where I'm putting these files in. And, I have referenced jquery-1.6.4,js as shown above which I also have it in the same folder, in addition to referencing jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js which is in the js folder in the current folder.

What am I getting wrong here? Isn't this the way to reference jQuery and jQueryUI?

*Browser used:* Mozilla Firefox 6.0.2

*Folder structure:*

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/abc.html

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/script.js

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/jquery-1.6.4.js

jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: [It works here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/BcGTg/). Maybe it's because you have the closing tags wrong? That is, `</body></div>` instead of `</div></body>`?

Comment: I just popped that into a jsfiddle, and it seems to have worked. http://jsfiddle.net/PGHHt/ Maybe try getting rid of the second jquery include? Or maybe some of those files don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Are the references point correct path? It is working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBDb8/) after removing the references.

Answer (score -1):

Despite the fact that (sorry) your code looks horrible (wrong order of html tags, you include jquery twice, ...) animate() doesn't work with `backgroundColor` out of the box and you will need the color plugin. mu is too short posted a link to a related thread in his comment on your post.

Comment: That's what jQueryUI is there for!

Comment: You are right, I only checked with jquery. Thanks.