# jQuery - The background is still not changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, background-color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - Background color not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625196/jquery-background-color-not-changing)

I know I have posted the similar question several times, but it is really confusing me why not working.

This is my latest version of the code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<style type="text/css"> 
#name{
background-color: #FFFFF2;
width: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="bgcolor" value="Change color"/>
<div id="name">
Abder-Rahman
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$("#bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#name").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#8B008B'},
        "fast");}
);
```

I want to notice that I have a folder called: `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom`, and this is where I'm putting these files in. And, I have referenced `jquery-1.6.4,js` as shown above which I also have it in the same folder, in addition to referencing `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js` which is in the `js` folder in the current folder.

What am I getting wrong here? Isn't this the way to reference `jQuery` and `jQueryUI`?

**EDIT**

*Browser used:* Mozilla Firefox 6.0.2

*Folder structure*:
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/abc.html
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/script.js
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/jquery-1.6.4.js
jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js

Thanks.

Comment: Do not open consecutive questions. Edit your previous one if you want to add something to it. Also, communicate with the people who answer you to ask about further clarification if their answer doesn't work for you. Don't just ask new questions without first trying to do your best to resolve the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put it in the window or document onload function? Is this page in the same folder as your scripts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bgcolor").click(function(){
    $("#name").animate(
        {backgroundColor: '#8B008B'},
        "fast");}
);
});
```

Comment: The page is in the same folder as my scripts. But, should I include an ``onload()` function? I think it works without this since I'm already including the script

Comment: If you don't put it in an onload function, then the script will run before the document is ready, which means your bgcolor element doesn't exist yet.

Comment: In this case, when I insert `onload` in the `<body>` tag, what should it be equal to? i.e; `onload=???``. Thanks

Comment: Also if you notice, I'm trying to run the script by triggering a button. So, isn't that enough for the document to be ready?

Comment: You're trying to add an event handler to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: How can I add the `onload` function in this case?

Comment: @Med-SWEng, I gave you the code in my answer, 34 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You probably somehow fail to include jQueryUI as that is where colour animation comes from. Is your jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js inside of a folder called js? You should also include your folder structure into this question as it's unclear what's wrong otherwise. Also you might want to look into the developer console of your browser if there is such a thing there (it might tell you of files failed to load or syntax errors you have). You also should mention what browser you're on to make it easier to help you.